# Simple PHP login not working

Tags: php, authentication, xampp

I'm very new to PHP and I'm trying to build a webpage with a login page. I think I understand it but my login page isn't working even though its very basic.

This is my file structure at the moment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfNqD.jpg

This is the idx (index):

```
<?php

error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );

include 'templates/header.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
    include 'controller/login.php';
}else{
    if($_SESSION['logged'] == true){
        include "controller/navigation.php";
    }else{
        include "idx.php";
    }
}

include 'templates/footer.php'
?>
```

This is the login.php template:

```
<?php
$out = "<form method='POST' action='idx.php'>
        <p>Login:</p>
        <label>Username:</label><input type='text' name ='username' required />
        <label>Password:</label><input type='password' name'password' required />
        <input type='submit' value='submit' name=submit'/>
        </form>";

echo $out;
```

This is the login.php controller:

```
<?php


include "view/login.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $urn=$_POST['username'];
    $pwd=$_POST['password'];

    $user = new user($urn);

    $worked = $user->authenticate($urn, $pwd);
    if($worked == true){
        $_SESSION['logged']=true;
        $_SESSION['username']=$urn;
        header('Location: controller/navigation.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo('Error');
    }
}
?>
```

This is the user model:

```
<?php
class user
{
    private $username;

    function __construct($username)
    {
        $this->username=$username;
    }

    function authenticate($username, $password)
    {
        if ($username == 'tim' && $password == 'ttt') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I'm just trying to get the form to take in the users details, check that they are "tim" and "ttt" and if so return a true value which will prompt the controller to change the header URL to navigation.php controller which in turn shows the navigation.php view which will just be a list of links. For some reason though whenever I hit submit nothing happens, it just stays on the login page.

I know this is a pretty basic thing to do but I've been stuck on it for a couple of days now and I've watched hours and hours of videos on it and read dozens of pages explaining how MVC works but can't get this simple thing done. Please can somebody tell me whats going wrong.

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Comment: Well it would help if you told **us** what is going wrong please

Comment: I can tell that this will not turn out well, if and once live. Plain text passwords will get you into deep doo-doo.

Comment: I don't think this is what's causing your current problem, but it looks like idx.php will include itself if the right conditions are met.

Comment: Alot of things need to be fixed here.  This is just on localhost,  I hope

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you start the session on every page you want to get or set session variables.

`session_start()`

It should be as simple as that, and it threw me for a loop for quite a while.

Have you considered using an MVC framework? They are very helpful for keeping everything tidy and organized, as well as providing a library of helpful functions and classes. CodeIgniter is a great and easy to use framework that is super lightweight. Laravel is a lot more invovled and is better suited for large scale projects.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this:**

```
<input type='password' name'password' required />
```

**This:**(You missed = `name='password'`)

```
<input type='password' name='password' required />
```

And dont forget to add `session_start()` at the very top of your page.

Answer (score -1):

I will share you my sample PHP login page setup.
it has 3 pages, index, admin, logout

index.php: Creates a form asking username and password, once correct username pssword given (here admin, password) it will create a new session "login". Once logged in it will redirect to the admin.php $validuser ensures previous login is true or not.

```
<?php
session_start();
$errorMsg = "";
$validUser = $_SESSION["login"] === true;

if (isset($_POST["sub"]))
    {
    $validUser = $_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "password";
    if (!$validUser) $errorMsg = "Invalid username or password.";
      else $_SESSION["login"] = true;
    }

if ($validUser)
    {
    header("Location: /admin.php");
    die();
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <table>
                <form name="input" action="" method="post">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input type="text" value="" id="username" name="username" />
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input type="password" value="" id="password" name="password" />
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sub" />
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

admin.php: Checks for session "login", if session was set then it will proceed further otherwise it will go to login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
    header('LOCATION:login.php');
    die();
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <center>
           <h1>Succesfully logged in</h1>
           <input type="button" value="Logout" onclick='window.open("/logout.php","_self")'/>
       </center>
    </body> 
</html>
```

logout.php: Clears the session, cookies and close them and returns to login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name() , '', 0, '/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
header("Location: /index.php");
die();
?>
```

put them in same folder it will work.

Comment: Please add some explanation... a lot of explanation... to this code only answer.